# Android Studio: Linear Layout not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout below a relative layout in my application. These are contained within a Constraint layout and a Scrollview.

Unfortunately one of my linear layouts is not appearing on my screen.

Below is my code, I have taken out some of the items such as TextViews just to make it more clear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewSingleClub">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="444dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="68dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradientsbackground"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible">

               //items inside here

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    //items inside here

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>


//This layout and everything inside doesn't appear

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                //items inside here
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Could anyone help me figure out why this Linear Layout isn't visible?

Comment: Not visible in the preview section in Android Studio? Or when running the app as well?

Comment: Check the error highlighted at the top of the scrollview "A ScrollView can have only one child"

Comment: In the preview!

Comment: Ahh interestin Ivan.. thanks for this. Would you suggest putting everything into a linear layout so?

Comment: I would wrap everything including the ConstraintLayout in the ScrollView

Comment: Edited last comment

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Is there a reason why putting the constraint layout inside is better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188177/discussion-between-ivan-wooll-and-minikate).

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will fix your issue

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="444dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="68dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradientsbackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                //items inside here

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    //items inside here

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                //items inside here

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```